# Jquery Autocomplete in a Dynamic Field using COCOON Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, cocoon-gem

Hi I am using cocoon in producing a nested field.

COCOON: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

The nested form/fields is 100% working and so Ive tried to integrate jQuery autocomplete in one nested field.

I've been following this gist (forked from map7): https://gist.github.com/xirukitepe/5132317

The autocomplete is working in the first/parent field, but isn't working on other succeeding nested fields.

Here is my code:

First I created the autocomplete controller....

```
class AutocompleteController < ApplicationController
    def categories
     if params[:term]
       like  = "%".concat(params[:term].concat("%"))
       categories = Category.where("lower (categories.code) LIKE lower(?)", like)
     else
       categories = Category.all
     end
     list = categories.map {|u| Hash[id: u.id, label: u.code, name: u.code]}
     render json: list            
   end
 end
```

Then in **item.rb**

I added the attr_accessor and one method...

```
attr_accessor :category_code
def category_code
          category.code if category_id
end
```

In **items_controller.rb**

```
def category_code=(code)
   category= Category.find_by_code(code)
   if category       
     self.category_id = category.id
   else              
     errors[:category_code] << "Invalid name entered"
   end               
end                 

def category_code      
   Category.find(category_id).name if category_id
end
```

Here is my coffee file:

```
$ ->
  $('input.x').autocomplete
  source: "/autocomplete/categories"
  select: (event,ui) -> $("input.xx").val(ui.item.id)
```

**routes.rb**

```
 match '/autocomplete/categories' => "autocomplete#categories"
  resources :project_procurement_management_plans do

    resources :attachments
    resources :items do

        member do
           put :edit_pmr_item
           get  :edit_item
        end
    end
  end
```

I'm calling it via class not ID, because nested attributes has different IDS and i dont know how to call it using JS.

Any workarounds will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I also need to do the same. Have you cracked it?

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you have to hook on the cocoon callbacks.

Basing my explanation in the examples from cocoon's README:

```
$('#tasks')
  .on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, task_to_be_added) {
    task_to_be_added.autocomplete({
      source: "/autocomplete/tags"
    });
})
```

You still have to do something like you did to initialize the itens that are already rendered before the dynamic addition.